# enable to parse json array into array

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

When I parsed only 4 entities cloudcover,humidity,tempc,tempf it ran successfully but when I parse image value then it gives an error to parse data from server. This is my json link [JSON File](http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Rajkot&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=xz9js2zhayhj4bcxuf7br2bg)

this is my JSON file

```
{
"data": {
        "current_condition": [
            {
            "cloudcover": "3",
            "humidity": "28",
            "observation_time": "04:47 PM",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "pressure": "1014",
            "temp_C": "33",
            "temp_F": "91",
            "visibility": "10",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [
            {
            "value": "Clear"
            }
            ],
            "weatherIconUrl": [
            {
            "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png"
            }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "NNW",
            "winddirDegree": "343",
            "windspeedKmph": "13",
            "windspeedMiles": "8"
            }
            ],
            "request": [
            {
            "query": "Rajkot, India",
            "type": "City"
            }
            ],
            "weather": [
            {
            "date": "2015-11-13",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "tempMaxC": "38",
            "tempMaxF": "100",
            "tempMinC": "27",
            "tempMinF": "80",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [
            {
            "value": "Sunny"
            }
            ],
            "weatherIconUrl": [
            {
            "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "NNE",
            "winddirDegree": "33",
            "winddirection": "NNE",
            "windspeedKmph": "13",
            "windspeedMiles": "8"
            },
            {
            "date": "2015-11-14",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "tempMaxC": "37",
            "tempMaxF": "98",
            "tempMinC": "26",
            "tempMinF": "78",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [
            {
            "value": "Sunny"
            }
            ],
            "weatherIconUrl": [
            {
            "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "NNE",
            "winddirDegree": "27",
            "winddirection": "NNE",
            "windspeedKmph": "13",
            "windspeedMiles": "8"
            },
            {
            "date": "2015-11-15",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "tempMaxC": "35",
            "tempMaxF": "95",
            "tempMinC": "25",
            "tempMinF": "76",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [
            {
            "value": "Sunny"
            }
            ],
            "weatherIconUrl": [
            {
            "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "N",
            "winddirDegree": "5",
            "winddirection": "N",
            "windspeedKmph": "14",
            "windspeedMiles": "9"
            },
            {
            "date": "2015-11-16",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "tempMaxC": "35",
            "tempMaxF": "96",
            "tempMinC": "25",
            "tempMinF": "77",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [
            {
            "value": "Sunny"
            }
            ],
            "weatherIconUrl": [
            {
            "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "NNE",
            "winddirDegree": "13",
            "winddirection": "NNE",
            "windspeedKmph": "16",
            "windspeedMiles": "10"
            },
            {
            "date": "2015-11-17",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "tempMaxC": "36",
            "tempMaxF": "96",
            "tempMinC": "25",
            "tempMinF": "76",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [
            {
            "value": "Sunny"
            }
            ],
            "weatherIconUrl": [
            {
            "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "N",
            "winddirDegree": "5",
            "winddirection": "N",
            "windspeedKmph": "17",
            "windspeedMiles": "10"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my code to parse json. it's run fine when i parse only for 4 elements. But when i trying to access the image "value" it's give a error enable to fetch data from server

```
    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONObject weatherData = jsono.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray currentData= weatherData.getJSONArray("current_condition");
    for (int i = 0; i < currentData.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = currentData.getJSONObject(i);

        Weather weather = new Weather();
        weather.setCloudcover(object.getString("cloudcover"));
        weather.setHumatity(object.getString("humidity"));
        weather.setTempc(object.getString("temp_C"));
        weather.setTempf(object.getString("temp_F"));
        JSONArray jsonArray = weatherData.getJSONArray("weatherDesc");
        for (int j=0;j< jsonArray.length();j++)
            {
            JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject("weatheDesc");
            weather.setImage(object1.getString("value"));
            weatherList.add(weather);
            }
        weatherList.add(weather);
    }
    return true;
    }

//------------------>>

} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should take a look to the Gson library, it populates your model with the json data making it so simple to parse.

Comment: but i don't know how to use gson

Comment: `weatherData.getJSONArray("weatherDesc")` doesn't work because the there is no array to get there. It should be `currentData.getJSONArray("weatherDesc")`

Comment: @cricket_007 Doesn't that should be `currentData.getJSONArray("weatherIconUrl");` as the image is inside of `weatherIconUrl` array ?

Comment: @YuvaRaj - If OP wants the image, then yes. But I think my comment was the cause of the initial error.

Comment: @cricket_007 Cool man :)

Comment: Anyways, @viratpuar - next time you have a question with an error, post the stacktrace along with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code from

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = weatherData.getJSONArray("weatherDesc");
  for (int j=0;j< jsonArray.length();j++)
    {
            JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject("weatheDesc");
            weather.setImage(object1.getString("value"));
            weatherList.add(weather);
     }
```

to,

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = currentData.getJSONArray("weatherIconUrl");
 for (int j=0;j< jsonArray.length();j++)
  {
    JSONObject object1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
    weather.setImage(object1.getString("value"));
   }
```

**Explanation** :

1. You're trying to fetch the image inside of `weatherDesc`. It actually available inside of `weatherIconUrl` array.
2. While looping `weatherIconUrl` array, you should navigate to inside `JSONObject` like,

   ```
    JSONObject object1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
   ```
3. Remove the `weatherList.add(weather);` from the loop as you have the same statement after the loop. It's not necessary.

Comment: `weatherData` should be `currentData`

Comment: Oh, i missed it. Thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Yeah, had to test with JavaScript to see that

Comment: Also, I think `weatherList.add(weather)` should be removed from the loop... OP has that line after the loop anyways - with the current setup, a new Weather object will be added for every image and twice for the last image.

Comment: but the JSONArray jsonArray = currentData.getJSONArray ask for (int index) not for "weatherIconUrl" it's still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the for loop with 1 line to get the image url:

```
weather.setImage(weatherData.getJSONArray("weatherIconUrl").getJSONObject(0)
                   .getString("value"));
```

Comment: This is fine when there have only one Object. But, if there are too many JSON Object inside inside JSON array, then it doesn't fetches the other images except the one at first.

Comment: True, but all of the weatherIconUrl arrays in the JSON data only have 1 item, so there is no need for a loop.

Comment: For the current data, it's ok. I'm just saying it might ve more since it is inside of `Array` not `Object` :)